# Why was EVA Unit 01 Crucified?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion

One part, for me anyway, that stuck out was the crucifixion by the Mass-Production EVA Units of EVA Unit 01 in *The End of Evangelion*. I just can't see the reason why EVA Unit 01 was crucified when Third Impact occurred. What was hoped to be gained by crucifying a mech of all things?

What was the reason for EVA Unit 01's crucifixion? Was it to start Third Impact?

I have not read the manga behind Evangelion, so I know I am missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a necessary part of the ritual they are doing but the exact details of it and how it works are unknown.

> **SCENE: SEELE monoliths**
>   SEELE 09?:
>   EVA-01 has been marked with the stigmata (sacred insignia).
>   All (chanting):
>   To restore the Tree of Life!
>   SEELE 01:
>   Our servants, the Eva series...
>   (Keel appears) Their existence has all been for this one moment.
>   (Eva series move to the positions of the Sephroticum and shine in circles around the cross of EVA-01)
>   [Script](http://nge.otaku.ru/scripts/episode26.htm)

A reason for the stigmata could be that GNR/Lilith also has them later on in the movie through which she absorbs the souls. Since EVA-01 is made from the body of Lilith these could possibly be caused by inflicting them on the EVA.
[image: Stigmata]